# Custom email validation for xxxx@my.csun.edu regex

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, plugins

Hello and great day to everyone.

I have JS code which validates all types of emails but i want to restrict the validation of email to one type of email eg : example **@my.csun.edu**

I want users with the **@my.csun.edu** as their email provider for example to only be validated, i want the users with other email providers such as @hotmail.com, @outlook.com , @gmail.com etc to be unable to register on the website.

Here is the code of regex - validation engine JS

```
 "email": {
                // Shamelessly lifted from Scott Gonzalez via the Bassistance Validation plugin http://projects.scottsplayground.com/email_address_validation/
                "regex": /^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i,
                "alertText": piereg_validation_engn[25]//"* Invalid email address"
            },
```

Please let me know if the code i have provided is not enough.

Sorry if my english is bad.

Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your simple requirement you can just use this regex:

```
regex = /^[^\s@]+@my\.csun\.edu$/i;
```

This will check if email address is ending with `@my.csun.edu` while allowing any non-space character before `@`.

Comment: It's a wordpress plugin actually. I've replaced the regex with the regex i've just provided and it doesn't work. It still let's users subscribe with that other emails.

Comment: I cannot test with WP but you can try: `"regex": /^[^\s@]+@my\.csun\.edu$/i,`

Answer (score 2):

Did you try http://emailregex.com? It should pretty much has all you need for email regular expression.